# POST facebook feed using graph api advanced parameters

Tags: javascript, facebook, post, feed

Has anyone been able to customize a Facebook feed post by using parameters like from, to, actions, etc, as documented here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

For example HTTP POSTing this `string`:

```
message=mymessage&access_token=mytokenstring
```

to

`https://graph.facebook.com/123456/feed` works fine and posts to your feed. Similarly parameters like picture, description, etc all work too.

But I can't get the more complicated parameters to work. Does anyone know the proper formatting? My guess below, and similar combinations, doesn't work at the moment:

```
message=mymessage&access_token=mytokenstring&from={"name":"Bob", "id":"123456"}
```

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I used PHP to implement actions:

```
$attachment = array
 (
 'access_token'=>$facebook->getAccessToken(),
 'message' => 'I\'ve been testing my IQ!',
 'name' => 'IC-YOUR-IQ',
 'caption' => 'This is my result:',
 'link' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/icyouriq/',
 'actions' => array('name'=>'Sweet FA','link'=>'http://www.facebookanswers.co.uk'),
 'description' => $cmsg,
 'picture' => 'http://www.facebookanswers.co.uk/img/misc/iq.jpg'
 );
```

The key line is the "actions" element. From my experiments I was only ever able to get one action to appear. But hopefully you get the picture.

The full article I wrote on this can be found here:

http://facebookanswers.co.uk/?p=270

Answer (score 0):

hmm that makes sense but doesn't appear to work. In the end they are expecting json I guess. Also I don't think 'from' or 'to' tags are supported when creating a post, but actions are. This string worked:

```
&actions=[{"name":"My%20Link","link":"http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2Fdownload.html"}]
```

Answer (score -1):

close, but it should be:

```
from[name]="Bob"&from[id]=123456
```

so `mainKey[subKey]=value&mainKey[subKey2]=value2`

Answer (score -1):

In javascript you can use the function ui , with the feed method, There is an example here:

http://aplicacionesfacebookparadummies.blogspot.com/2011/09/compartir-en-aplicaciones-facebook.html

Answer (score -1):

```
fields=posts.fields(message,actions)
```